# How to insert primary key in database?

Tags: c#, winforms

as `emp_id` is pk and it has no textbox

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO cntc_employee (emp_id,emp_f_name,emp_l_name,emp_alias,emp_contact_no,emp_address,emp_company,emp_bdate) VALUES(@fname,@lname,@alias,@contact,@address,@company,@bdate)";
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", ????);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alias", textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", textBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", textBox6.Text);
```

For `empid` I don't know which command to use

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", ????);`

Comment: What do you mean? What is the value of `empid` that you want to insert?

Comment: If it has no textbox, then where is the value coming from? Going out on a limb here, do you mean to say it is auto-generated by the database (i.e. an `identity` column)?

Comment: you need to enter the value of the empid there if the column is AUTO-INCREMENTED column (IDENTITY) then you should leave that column.

Comment: have you set the identity of your primary key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* `emp_id` is an *automatically generated* Primary Key, simply *don't* specify it in the column list (and thus there is no reason to supply a binding value) - this includes [IDENTITY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) columns in SQL Server and [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) columns in MySQL, etc.

```
// Additional columns removed for sake of example
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO cntc_employee (emp_f_name) values (@fname)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", textBox1.Text);
```

Assuming this is the case, then the database will see that `emp_id` has not been assigned a value and will use the "next" available value for the column when the record is inserted.

If `emp_id` is *not* an automatically generated surrogate Key, then find out who designed the system and ask them what the value should be and how it should be generated :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want that your empid increased automatically then you have to set the IDENTITY of it.

If you are using MSSQL then use below image to set IDENTITY of table.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the `EmpId` is `Identity` in the SQL **then no need to pass it**,

`cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO cntc_employee (emp_f_name,emp_l_name,emp_alias,emp_contact_no,emp_address,emp_company,emp_bdate) VALUES(@fname,@lname,@alias,@contact,@address,@company,@bdate)";`

if it is not then you **need to mention or generate the logic in your Programming Language to create the Emp ID**

Answer (score 1):

If you realy want to insert a specific value to the field emp_id for some reason, you have to set Identity_insert to on.

```
// "SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . ] table { ON | OFF }"

cmd.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.cntc_employee ON; ";
cmd.CommandText += "INSERT INTO cntc_employee (emp_id,emp_f_name,emp_l_name,emp_alias,emp_contact_no,emp_address,emp_company,emp_bdate) VALUES(@empid,@fname,@lname,@alias,@contact,@address,@company,@bdate)";
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", textBoxXx.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alias", textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", textBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", textBox6.Text);
```

[SET IDENTITY_INSERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188059.aspx)